# show() function does not work for dynamically generated list item

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
<div id="header2">
    <ul id="boards"></ul>
</div>
```

initially i have an empty unordered list. after clicking a button, list items generated dynamically containing html codes will be added using javascript.

```
<script>
$("#header2 ul").append('<li id="b'+i+'"> <a id="back" class="button" href="#" style="float:right;">Back</a><a id="data_link" class="button" href="#" style="float:right;">Data</a> \n <a id="board_link" class="button" href="#" style="float:right;">Board</a>\n <h1>Kanban Board</h1>\n <div id="output"></div> \n <div class="clear"></div> \n<textarea id="data_output" rows="20" cols="100"> </textarea></li>');

$("#header2").hide();
$("#header ul").on('click', function (){
    $("#"+this.id).show();
});

</script>
```

Now, i only want to select one item from the list so it will only display the block of code that it has but the show() function does not work with dynamically generated list. please help me thank you.

here's the code

```
<h1>Kanban Boards</h1>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Add Board</button>

<div id="header">
    <ul id="tabs"></ul>
</div>
<div id="header2">
    <ul id="boards"></ul>
</div>

<script>
var i=0;
function myFunction()
{
    var x;

    var person=prompt("Please enter board name","My Kanban");

    if (person!=null){
        x=person;
        $("#header ul").append('<li id="'+i+'" onclick="alert("hello")"><a class="button" href="#">'+x+'</a> </li>');
        $("#header2 ul").append('<li id="b'+i+'"> <a id="back" class="button" href="#" style="float:right;">Back</a><a id="data_link" class="button" href="#" style="float:right;">Data</a> \n <a id="board_link" class="button" href="#" style="float:right;">Board</a>\n <h1>Kanban Board</h1>\n <div id="output"></div> \n <div class="clear"></div> \n<textarea id="data_output" rows="20" cols="100"> </textarea></li>');
        i++;
    }
}
$("#header2").hide();
$("#header ul").on('click', function (){
    $("#"+this.id).show();
});


</script>
```

Comment: Your logic looks odd. First you hide `#header2`, how then click on an `ul` within it?

Comment: You're hiding the parent element when the child element event is dependent on it. Pretty sure you can't use a click event on a hidden object unless your manually triggering it.

Comment: The problem is not with the `.show()` not working on dynamically created elements.  The problem is you can't click the `ul` inside the `#header` because the `#header` is **hidden**

Comment: oh that's a typo im sorry. im actually targetting #header instead of #header2...i just didnt include the code to header but it also contains a list. when i click a list in #header, the corresponding element in #header2 should show but i cannot do it

Comment: @teemu the function is called repeatedly

Comment: Hmm... After reading your comment about typo, I'd say there was a good link to solve the issue already in this thread, but it was removed... Anywway, please show the real code you have (without typos this time ; ), the provided snippet actually doesn't implement your problem at all (as the post doesn't tell what's not working either).

Comment: here i've uploaded what i think is needed for my problem to be understood.

Comment: i have a **dynamically generated** list and i want to select only **one** item from that list to be displayed but i don't know how. 

i tried the show() and hide() functions but they don't work on dynamically generated list. nothing happens to it.

i have also read about on() but i only used it when a link is clicked. i have no idea on how to use it in showing or hiding list items.

do you have any idea for this problem?

Answer (score 0):

You cant click on an element you are hiding. You hide `#header2` but are trying to click on the `ul` inside of it, that gets hidden along with the div.

Comment: so i'll just unhide the parent wrap but if i select one element from the list, i want the other elements to be hidden..how can i do that if my elements are dynamically generated?